# Generalizing the von Mises Criterion to Complex Stress Tensors

Tags: stress-energy-momentum-tensor, complex-numbers, continuum-mechanics, stress-strain

I was deriving the von Mises maximum distortion energy criterion:

$${\displaystyle \sigma _{\text{v}}={\sqrt {{\frac {1}{2}}\left[(\sigma _{1}-\sigma _{2})^{2}+(\sigma _{2}-\sigma _{3})^{2}+(\sigma _{3}-\sigma _{1})^{2}\right]}}}\tag1$$

I did the following steps:

1. Define the Cauchy stress tensor $\sigma_{ij}$
2. Calculate the deviatoric part of the stress tensor i.e. the $s_{ij}=\sigma_{ij}-\frac{1}{3}{\displaystyle \operatorname {tr} (\mathbf {\sigma_{ij}} )}$
3. The desired relation now follows from ${\displaystyle \sigma _{\text{v}}}=\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}{\displaystyle \langle  {s_{ij}} , {s_{ij}} \rangle _{\mathrm {F} }}}$, where ${\displaystyle \langle \mathbf {A} ,\mathbf {B} \rangle _{\mathrm {F} }} $ is the [Frobenius inner product,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_inner_product)

$${\displaystyle \langle \mathbf {A} ,\mathbf {B} \rangle _{\mathrm {F} }=\sum _{i,j}{\overline {A_{ij}}}B_{ij}\,=\mathrm {Tr} \left({\overline {\mathbf {A} ^{T}}}\mathbf {B} \right)\equiv \mathrm {Tr} \left(\mathbf {A} ^{\!\dagger }\mathbf {B} \right)}$$

The usage of the Frobenius inner product made me wonder if we could generalize the inputs of the stress tensor to complex numbers? In the end, the Frobenius product gives scalar values so the final value would still represent some yield criterion, but maybe it could be used to model some complex cases with vibrations?